# SQL Unable to remove CHAR(13)

Tags: sql-server, replace, carriage-return

I am looking at a table which has had data items entered into it with a CHAR(13) in it.

I can identify the rows easily enough with:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Preferences
WHERE   PreferenceName LIKE '%' + CHAR(13) + '%'
```

So from this I know the lines which have the control character in them.  However when I try to remove these characters with:

```
UPDATE  dbo.Preferences
SET     PreferenceName = REPLACE(PreferenceName, CHAR(13), '')
WHERE   PreferenceName LIKE '%' + CHAR(13) + '%'
```

I get a 0 row(s) affected message and of course no updates.  I need to tidy this data up as it affects filtering. (I can select with a like but not an equals which is of course a lot slower)

Any ideas why this won't work as expected?

Comment: You are selecting from `tmp.dc_Preferences_bbb` and updating `dbo.Preferences`.  Is that a mistake?

Comment: Just noticed the same myself. Thats a typo, multiple queries in one window, pasted wrong one, but one is a view of the other

Comment: So, the first one returns rows, but the second does not? Can you use the schema in the first one as well?

Comment: Yeah.  I can read the rows, but it won't allow me to clean the data. I've just got to the point where I'm doubting myself now. It looks straight forward, but doesn't work.

Comment: Are you running the two queries in the same DB?  Try with a more complete table name like `yourDatabaName.dbo.Preferences`.

Comment: Ok SSMS just started throwing memory errors. So I shut it down, opened it back up and it worked. Switch it off and on again - fixes eveything.  Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

I just did a testing

```
    ;WITH testdata(ID,s)AS
    (
       SELECT 1,'This is a string' UNION ALL
       SELECT 2,'This is the sencode string'+CHAR(13) UNION ALL
       SELECT 3,'This is the third string'+CHAR(10) UNION
       SELECT 4,'This is'+CHAR(13)+' a '+CHAR(13)+' string containing special character!'+CHAR(13)
    )
    SELECT *,'After replaced:'+REPLACE(s,CHAR(13),'') AS replaced FROM testdata
    WHERE CHARINDEX(CHAR(13),s)>0
```

```
ID          s                                                  replaced
----------- -------------------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2           This is the sencode string
                        After replaced:This is the sencode string
4           This is
 a 
 string containing special character!
 After replaced:This is a  string containing special character!
```